# Object doesn't support method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run the following code, but get an error in the gameLoop function saying: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'update'.

I'm a beginning JavaScript programmer. Can you spot what is wrong with this code?

```
function Core(context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fps = 500;
    this.sprite = new Sprite();
}

Core.prototype.run = function() {
    setInterval(this.gameLoop, this.fps); // <<<< PROBLEM
}

Core.prototype.gameLoop = function () {
    this.update();
    this.draw();
}

Core.prototype.update = function () {
    this.sprite.x += 50;
    this.sprite.y += 50;
}

Core.prototype.draw = function () {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    this.context.fillRect(this.sprite.x, this.sprite.y, 50, 50);
    this.context.fillText('x: ' + this.sprite.x + ' y: ' + this.sprite.y, 10, 250);
}
```

Comment: Fixed code: http://pastebin.com/xuNTQSrP - `this` in `Core.prototype.gameLoop` did not resolve to the the expected one, because of `setInterval`.

Comment: @Milosz: No need, it only matters that they be define when `gameLoop` is **called**, not when it's defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by how a function is called, not where or how it's defined. The problem is that `setInterval` doesn't call your code  with the correct `this` value. To fix:

```
function Core(context) {
    var self = this;

    this.context = context;
    this.fps = 500;
    this.sprite = new Sprite();
    this.boundGameLoop = function() {
        self.gameLoop();
    };
}

Core.prototype.run = function() {
    setInterval(this.boundGameLoop, this.fps);
}
```

On JavaScript engines that have ES5 features (or if you're using an ES5 "shim"), you can change `Core` to:

```
function Core(context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fps = 500;
    this.sprite = new Sprite();
    this.boundGameLoop = this.gameLoop.bind(this);
}
```

More reading:

- [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [Function#bind](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5) in the ES5 spec

---

Side note: Your code relies on the horror that is [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9). (All of your function assignments — `Core.prototype.run = function() { ... }`) need semicolons after the closing `}`.)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is  [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
 setInterval(this.gameLoop.bind(this), this.fps)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try reshuffling your code so that you declare update before you call it, e.g.

```
Core.prototype.update = function () {
    this.sprite.x += 50;
    this.sprite.y += 50;
}

Core.prototype.gameLoop = function () {
    this.update();
    this.draw();
}
```